# Document class downloads for LyX

Tags: lyx, document-classes, resources

I'm looking for document class downloads for LyX, i.e. .cls and .layout files for multiple purposes, mostly life sciences article writing. Anyone familiar with a source for a collection of those?

Answer (score 1):

All available layout files are already part of the default LyX installation. For other classes you have to create new or adopt an existing layout file.